# How do I create a two-dimensional array from a vector of vectors with ndarray?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, rust

I am trying to use the `ndarray` crate to do some bioinformatics, but I can't seem to be able to create a matrix dynamically.

I have vectors of booleans that I would like to combine into a two-dimensional array. However, trying to flatten the vectors and using `into_shape` does not retain a correct order of the elements.

Thus I tried to create an empty array and concatenate rows into it, however this gives me an error I cannot comprehend. I know the empty array does not have the same dimensions but I cannot find a way to cast an empty array to the correct type and dimensions.

```rust
use ndarray::{concatenate, Array, Axis, Ix2};

fn main() {
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    let vector_of_vectors = vec![
        vec![true, false, true],
        vec![false, true, false],
    ];

    let mut matrix: Array<bool, Ix2> = ndarray::array![];
    for array in vector_of_vectors.iter() {
        matrix = concatenate![Axis(0), matrix, Array::from(array.clone())];
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:18
   |
12 |         matrix = concatenate![Axis(0), matrix, Array::from(array.clone())];
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 2 elements, found one with 1 element
   |
   = note: expected struct `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
              found struct `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation for `ndarray`:

- ["Conversions from Nested Vecs/Arrays"](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#conversions-from-nested-vecsarrays)

### Known row and column length

```rust
use ndarray::{Array2, Axis};

fn main() {
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    let rand_vec = vec![
        vec![true, false, true],
        vec![false, true, false],
    ];

    let mut arr = Array2::<bool>::default((2, 3));
    for (i, mut row) in arr.axis_iter_mut(Axis(0)).enumerate() {
        for (j, col) in row.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            *col = rand_vec[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc16677ad9ba401c898515aa7dcd8588)

### Unknown row and column length

The documentation suggests to efficiently flatten the `Vec` using [`extend_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_slice) and pass the flattened result to [`Array2::from_shape_vec`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.from_shape_vec):

```rust
use ndarray::Array2;

fn main() {
    // A Vec<Vec<bool>> with a random length of rows and columns
    let rand_vec = gen_rand_vec();

    let mut data = Vec::new();

    let ncols = rand_vec.first().map_or(0, |row| row.len());
    let mut nrows = 0;

    for i in 0..rand_vec.len() {
        data.extend_from_slice(&rand_vec[i]);
        nrows += 1;
    }

    let arr = Array2::from_shape_vec((nrows, ncols), data).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8088d54e1ab405cc6c75d694d7617b9a)

Given the former input for `rand_vec`, both examples will give you:

```
[
  [true, false, true],
  [false, true, false],
]
```

Comment: the doc advice to use `Array2::zeros` if you shape is already known

Comment: Thank you so much! This works for me when the lengths are known at compile time. However in my despair last night I typoed the axis to 0 and not 1. So to all the other noobies change Axis 0 to 1 when adding columns instead of rows.

Comment: I still cant wrap my head around creating a matrix column-wise from dynamically sized data using ```from_shape_vec``` but there seems to be a pull request coming through adding ```try_append_row``` and ```try_append_column``` methods to 2D arrays [https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/pull/932](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/pull/932). So this will add some ergonomics in the future!